# How to find an XML node from a line and column number in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Given the following

- A line number
- A column number
- An XML file

(Where the line and column number represent the '<' character of a node)

Using the XDocument API how do I find the XNode at that position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
XNode FindNode(string path, int line, int column)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
    var query =
        from node in doc.DescendantNodes()
        let lineInfo = (IXmlLineInfo)node
        where lineInfo.LineNumber == line
        && lineInfo.LinePosition <= column
        select node;
    return query.LastOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [LINQ to XML and Line Numbers](http://blog.linqexchange.com/index.php/linq-to-xml-and-line-numbers/) on LINQ Exchange gives an example using [IXmlLineInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.ixmllineinfo.aspx) that corresponds to what you're looking for:

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(fileName, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
var line = from x in xml.Descendants()
           let lineInfo = (IXmlLineInfo)x
           where lineInfo.LineNumber == 21
           select x;

foreach (var item in line)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: @KenWhite Ok. Updated to include a relevant code block copied from the article.